# Problems using a variable as array key in html5 script

Tags: php, html

I'm currently trying to start using php for some procedural generations and wanted to display my functions with a bar chart:

```
<?php 
$seed = 58521672597513854781922;
global $randomArray;

for ($i=-1000; $i<1001; $i++) {
    $temp = $seed/($i+0.1)^0.5;
    $tempRes = $temp.'';
    $randomArray[$i] =  $tempRes[5];   
}
?>

<div>
  <canvas id="c3" width="600" height = "200" style="border:solid 1px #000000;"></canvas>
  <div>
    <button onclick="Vertical_line();return true;">draw array</button>
  </div> 
</div>

<script>
   var c3 = document.getElementById("c3");
   var c3_context = c3.getContext("2d");

       function Vertical_line() {
         <?php
            for($j=0;$j<sizeof($randomArray);$j++){
            $height = 100 - 10*$randomArray[$j];
         ?>
         c3_context.moveTo(<?php echo 300+$j;?>, 200);
         c3_context.lineTo(<?php echo 300+$j;?>, <?php echo $height;?>);
         c3_context.strokeStyle = "red";
         c3_context.stroke();
        <?php }?>
       }
</script>
```

i don't understand why the variable $j as key reference in my array doesnt work. If i replace it by numbers manually to draw a single entry of my array it works without problems, if i set a variable as absolute number and use it as key it works too, just when i use a variable that changes its value it wont display anything.

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: What do you see in a html-source code for your function `Vertical_line`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: you need to first define `$randomArray` variable on line 14

Comment: yeah, sorry, i left out the part where i set the values, just consider the array filled with numbers from 0 to 9, edited in a part where i fill the array.

Comment: the code is supposed to draw vertical lines in the canvas, the length of those lines is defined by the values of the array (0 to 9). if i use a number as key it gives me a row of lines with the height defined by that entry, the number of lines fits with the number of values in the array. If i dont specify the key with a number but use the $j nothing is drawn.

Comment: its weird, when i use the variable the source code properly shows all the lines which are supposed to be drawn, but they just aren't drawn O_o

Comment: Check developers console for errors.

Comment: i use eclipse, it doesnt show any error

Comment: Do a console.log on your height values?... possible they are 0?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for helping out, found the error, was a problem with the negative key for my array, simple oversight :), thanks @ u_mulder for reminding me to look at the source code, i had to scroll quite a while to see the error ^^

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run Php inside ofJavascript, Php always runs as soon as the page loads, you want to create a JS function to do the job u wish

Comment: php runs on the server, well before the page loads and it can output javascript